What is the purpose of these wires close to the wing leading edge of the F-117 nighthawk?
Noticed two pairs of wires that seem to run along/underneath the leading edge of the F-117.
What is the likely purpose of these wires? They exist on the other side as well.

Could be almost anything.  My guess is they are fuel level sensor wires.

Or FBW signals to elevon PCUs.  Nav lights.  Something tells me something to do with the FBW controls or some other kind of very sensitive electronics, because they went to the trouble to separate two small harnesses with all that duplicate Adel clamp hardware when you would expect a single run. So perhaps RF emission interference from each harness was a thing that required them to be separated.

@JohnK they also routed the wires as twisted pairs to minimize rf interference/emissions.

@Jpe61 the other purpose for the separation may just be for damage tolerance from shrapnel, where each run is for one of two FBW PCUs. Same reason you'd have dual control cable runs, one on each side of the fuselage, in an airliner.

It is very likely an analog sensor of some sort (my 50 cents on fuel sensor): cables are too small to bring high currents, and 2 conductors are almost surely an analog signal not a digital one (while 2-wire protocols exist, they would require power and GND wires, so minimum 4 wires for digital).

@mins Yes, solutions exist like PLC and POTS (I2C still require separate power) but are very uncommon in embedded systems design.
